# Can no longer forward X11 with MobaXterm

Tags: linux, ssh, xorg, x11-forwarding, mobaxterm

Until today, I was able to effortlessly enable X11-forwarding with [MobaXterm](https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/) from my Linux laptop to my Windows laptop.

However, as of today, I am suddenly getting this error message whenever I try to start a graphical application over SSH:

```
$ xeyes
MoTTY X11 proxy: unable to connect to forwarded X server: Network error: Connection refused
Error: Can't open display: localhost:10.0
```

I did recently install some updates on my Linux machine, all of which appear to be kernel-level; perhaps they broke something.

After getting this error, I also updated MobaXterm to the latest version, to no avail. I've tried restarting the X11 server on its end, no luck.

Any ideas on what's going wrong?

Comment: I have the same issue and haven't been able to resolve it related to MobaXterm but I was able to get something working with VcXsrv Windows X Server and Bitvise SSH Client

Comment: Same here but it started about a year ago. Still haven't found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I got similar error while trying to launch firefox for example.

```
MoTTY X11 proxy: unable to connect to forwarded X server: Network error: 
Connection refused
Unable to init server: Broadway display type not supported: localhost:12.0
Error: cannot open display: localhost:12.0
```

Restarting MobaXterm's X server (X server -> Stop X Serve and X server -> Start X Server) did fix the error for me.